# Where to import stylesheets for components in (`create-react-app`) React.js app?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have created a new React.js app using `create-react-app`.

For each component (e.g. `src/components/ComponentX.js`), I have created a separate stylesheet (`src/styles/ComponentX.css`), and imported it as follows `import "../styles/ComponentX.css"`.

This has in turn resulted in a separate `<style>...</style>` section for each imported stylesheet on every page. Thus, the stylesheets are global (which makes sense for SPA?), albeit not concatenated as described [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-stylesheet/):

> In development, expressing dependencies this way allows your styles to be reloaded on the fly as you edit them. In production, all CSS files will be concatenated into a single minified .css file in the build output.

Since it doesn't seem to affect the functionality of the React.js app, where stylesheets are imported, where should I import my stylesheets? Local to the components or in `src/index.js`?

**Bonus**: What about components sharing the same stylesheet? Should both import it, if following the local approach?

Comment: If your stylesheet is global, import it in only one file, but if you prefer CSS modules, they should be local for the components.

Comment: there is no wrong if two components are sharing the same CSS file, all CSS file can either be stored in a separate `style` folder or a `CSS file +  component` can be stored together in a folder or you can write all CSS style in src global `index.css`

Comment: @Digambernegi So it's not a problem if two separate components `import` the same stylesheet?

Comment: @SonuBamniya Should I import the stylesheet in `index.js` or `ComponentX.js`?

Comment: if you are importing your CSS as `import "./filename.css"` then import it only in index, because it will effect throught the application, but if you import it `import styles from "filename.module.css"` then import in local `ComponentX.js`. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/#buttonmodulecss

Comment: @Shuzheng if two components share same style you can write it in `index.css`, in that case you are not required to import `index.css` in those components.

Comment: @Digambernegi Writing lots of unrelated styles in `index.css` is not easy to maintain IMHO

Answer (score 2):

My suggestions about the styles are the following:

1. Avoid to import CSS files at component-level, unless they are modules, see below
2. Use CSS modules at component-level and ensure that you are not changing some global style in these CSS files (like `a` or `table` styles, or even framework-related styles like, just to give you an example, `.a-class-used-by-material-ui`. Really, never do that at component-level!)
3. If you really need to change a framework-related style, and there is no built-in method to do that, only if you have no other way at all, create a `styles` directory and add a file like `a-framework-name.css` and add the overrides here, only if you are completely aware about the consequences (potential responsiveness loss, incongruity with other styles, opinionated changes and other)
4. Put a file in your `styles` directory, like `index.css` and import it in the root `index.js` file to reset some CSS default (to normalize)
5. If you decide to use CSS-in-JS, try to avoid mixing it with other techniques
6. Shared styles can be put in a module like `styles/shared.module.scss` (consider that, if you have a shared style and you start use the same style in a lot of components, it would be hard to predict the impact of a change made to the style. Let say you have the `height` set to `3rem` then you decide to change it to be `3.5rem`, you may broke something without realizing it)
7. Of course, import CSS modules in the proper way, something like `import style from "style.module.css"`, this should avoid name name conflicts between style names since, if configured correctly, the name of a class like `.fancyClassName` will be transformed to `style_fancyClassName__3xnbQ` when generating the final code
8. If you want more control over CSS properties values (like "my accent color must be #AC0955"), you should consider CSS variables
9. Consider SCSS or similar solutions too, if you can take some advantage with them in your scenario

Comment: Is it a problem if two components import the same stylesheet?

Comment: No it is not, the only point I can see as a warning is that, if you have a shared style, then you start use the same style in a lot of components, it would be hard to predict the impact on a change made to the style. Let say you have the `height` set to `3rem` then you decide to change it to be `3.5rem`, you may broke something without realizing it. But, by itself, to share some style is OK.

Comment: Added this comment to the answer too

Answer (score 1):

Generally I'd advise to import them locally, as this will enable you to later introduce per-page code-splitting if you wish to, whereas I don't see any advantage to importing them in your application root.

This approach should also make it easier to spot when you've forgotten to import one of your sheets and enables you to not always have to edit an extra file (your entry file) when adding a component.

However I'd also suggest you have a look at [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/), a library for inlining your styles alongside your components.

Comment: Thanks. If two components share the same stylesheet should they import it both? Is there any issues with important the same stylesheet from two components?

Comment: Yes they should, as each component should be usable without depending on the import of another one. It will lead to no issues, as the assets will be deduplicated at build time.

Answer (score 1):

This is more architectural type of question. Importing CSS with your module is fine. There's whole debate between CSS-in-JS (what you're doing now) vs traditional CSS.

> Thus, the stylesheets are global

CSS is global. If you want to scope your CSS either use some kind of technique like [BEM](https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/) or completely different technology [CSS modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) which will generate unique class names for your components.

It's also perfectly fine to have one central CSS file (like `index.css` or `styles.css`) where you import all other CSS files. Then you only import this central CSS file in one place and it will in turn import other stylesheets.

That is my preferred approach actually but it has some downsides - for example dynamically loading the stylesheet only when the component loads etc.

Comment: Thank you. CSS modules are also global (they result in a separate `<style>...</style>` section), but the class names are generated uniquely for the particular module to prevent naming clashes. Since React.js is for creating SPAs, i.e. there is *only* a single page, it needs to include style sections for each imported CSS file?

Comment: How would you import all stylesheets in `src/styles/*` into `index.css`? Won't I need Sass for this? I once read that importing from plain CSS files results in multiple HTTP requests, where as Sass doesn't?

Comment: @Shuzheng No, simply use `@import url` directive inside `index.css`. That works with regular CSS, you don't need a preprocessor for that. Multiple HTTP requests might not be such a bad thing depending on how many stylesheets you have and if you use HTTP2. You can use a build tool to concatenate all you stylesheets into one but  that's a matter of build process which is a different topic. (I always minify and concatenate my production builds)

Answer (score 1):

If you have global styles that is going to apply on whole application. Put it in App.css or at global level. Else for each component make a folder like Homepage -> In that create Homepage.jsx and Homepage.styles.scss , It will be better. Else use styled-component no need to import

Comment: The styles in `Homepage.styles.scss` will also affect the entire application, right?

Answer (score 0):

[This is the project structure i am working on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yHf8.png)

Each component has its own .css file. Style in this file is wrapped by a separate class corresponding to the component name. File index.jsx will import "./index.less" (normally index.css but my project uses lessjs).
The project also has a central CSS file in common/style/index.less where commonly used classes are defined (like: .font-size-12, .font-size-14, .color-primary, ...)

Comment: This does not answer the question. Pleased review [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I think I have answered the question: "Where should I import my stylesheets? Local to the components or in src/index.js?"
My answer is: local to the component. Of course, after building the project with webpack, they will be merged into a single file. But writing css in components makes them more manageable.Sorry, English is not my language. Please forgive me if my answer is difficult to understand. Thanks for the comment.
Sorry, English is not my language. Please forgive me if my answer is difficult to understand. Thanks for the comment.